# .reamlをサーバー上に置いて簡易APIとして使えないだろうか？

Tags: realm

ふと思いついたので質問します。
.reamlファイルををサーバー上に置いて簡易APIとして使えないだろうか？
使用用途は商品バーコード、画像URL、商品名、カテゴリーのレコードを10万行程度。

CRUDには様々の方法が思いつくのだけど、ベストな手法を知りたいです。

Comment: 因みにFirebase Hosting上でdeployしようとしているのですが動くものでしょうか?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RealmのNode.js版はサーバーサイドで動作しますのでREST APIなどを介してRealmを扱うことができます。
https://news.realm.io/jp/news/realm-node-js-express-blog-tutorial/

こちらはNodejsとExpress、Realmを用いてブログサービスを作成するサンプルです。

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/RealmTodo
こちらは同じくExpressを使ってTodoアプリケーションを作るサンプルです。

いずれもREST APIを介してRealmを更新したり、JSONでデータを受け取ったりします。

またはWindows AzureとRealm .NET版を使う選択肢もあります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました！因みにFirebase Hosting上でdeployしようとしているのですが動くものでしょうか?懸念点などありましたらご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 試したことはないですけどNode.jsが動く環境なら動くので大丈夫じゃないでしょうか。ダメだったら教えてください。

Comment: 承知しました。ありがとうございます！そしていつもアプリではRealmにはお世話になっており頭が上がりません。今後共よろしくお願いします。